# Fetch route plus crossings from OSRM

Tags: osrm

While fetching a driving route from OSRM, is it possible to fetch the names of the roads that feed into that path (so crossings and side roads)? If so, how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can only retrieve the names of the roads that are part of the route. This information is available if you pass the option `steps=true`.

The `.routes[].legs[].steps[]` object ([`RouteStep`](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.15.2/api/#routestep-object)) has a property `name` that contains the street name.

Comment: Can I detect *that* there is a crossing? If so, I could just search the surrounding for streets.

Comment: Yes, there is an array of [`Intersection`](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.15.2/api/#intersection-object) objects for each `RouteStep` object that contains the location of each intersection along the way.

Comment: Super; those intersections have bearings, so if I use location of the intersection + bearing + a distance of (say) 5m, I get a point on the intersecting road, and I can use an OSRM "nearest" request to find its name.